# how to get point cloud data from Kinect ROS

Tags: ros-melodic, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello there ! I am using Kinect v4 in our lab, I successfully was able to install ROS on Kinect v4.

what we are trying to do is to get point clouds from Kinect. Is there any way to do it  by using python ??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/384523/how-to-get-point-cloud-data-from-kinect-ros/) by [YoungjoonHong](https://answers.ros.org/users/81435/youngjoonhong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-08-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

what we are trying to do is to get point clouds from Kinect. Is there any way to do it by using python ??

You need to install the driver first.

> Take a look at this package:   Drivers

https://github.com/ZiqiChai/k4a-ros or https://github.com/microsoft/Azure_Kinect_ROS_Driver

> Is there any way to do it by using python ??

In your python subscribe to point cloud Topics.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
import pcl
from sensor_msgs.msg import PointCloud2
import sensor_msgs.point_cloud2 as pc2
import ros_numpy

def callback(data):
    print(data)
    # Enter your code here


rospy.init_node('listener', anonymous=True)
rospy.Subscriber("/<Your topic name>", PointCloud2, callback)
rospy.spin()
```

---

Originally posted by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) with karma: 1622 on 2021-08-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [YoungjoonHong](https://answers.ros.org/users/81435/youngjoonhong/) on 2021-08-19**:
I appreciate your kind and detailed comment !!